# How to get sum of grouped count mysql

Tags: mysql

My query is just returning and doing group by but I need the sum of groups. . Code:

```
select   a.date, count(*) 
from employee a 
inner join department b on a.uid = b.id 
where date(a.date) between current_date-2 and current_date  
group by 1 having count(*)>1 
order by date
```

**My Output:**

```
           date       count
    November 18,2019    2
    November 18,2019    4
    November 18,2019    2
    November 19,2019    2
    November 19,2019    2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
           date       count
    November 18,2019    8
    November 19,2019    4
```

Comment: Simply `GROUP BY date`

Comment: Maybe we are expecting return from `SELECT DATE(a.date) .... GROUP BY DATE(a.date)` ...  It's very strange that MySQL would return "November 18,2019" as the return from a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column. Looks to me like a.date migt be DATETIME, including a time component. If we want those values collapsed into a single row, then we could lop of the time component (using the DATE()` function) so we are operating on just the DATE value. There's not enough information provided for a diagnosis; i'm just suggesting one likely possibility.

Comment: There is no case that this query would return the results you posted.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What type is the `date` column and is the join with department really relevant for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess here. There's not enough information for a diagnosis.

It's very strange that MySQL would return `'November 18,2019'` from a DATE or DATETIME datatype. My guess is that `a.date` is a DATETIME datatype and includes a time component.

Looks like we want to lop off the time component, to just a DATE value, and then group by that.

Again, I'm just guessing at the problem.

Personally, I would write the query something like this:

```
 SELECT DATE(a.date)    AS `date_` 
      , COUNT(*)        AS `cnt_`
   FROM employee a
   JOIN department b
     ON b.id = a.uid
  WHERE a.date >=  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -2 DAY
    AND a.date <   DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL +1 DAY
  GROUP BY DATE(a.date)
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ORDER BY DATE(a.date)
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The previous query demonstrated a typical pattern, when we want to get total count by day, when we have a DATETIME column; doing the GROUP BY on an expression that returns a DATE value, rather than doing the GROUP BY on a DATETIME column.

The previous query head-scratchingly ignored how the query returns a weird-ass `'November 18,2019'` apparently VARCHAR value, how `DATE()` of that would produce anything other than an error or NULL, and how that could possibly satisfy a BETWEEN condition of DATE values.

But setting all of that confusion aside, and to attempt to more directly answer the question that was asked:  how to get a SUM of counts.

One way to do that would be to take the query  that is returning the counts, and turn that into an inline view.

Note that this is a *wrong* way to approach achieving the result, but to more directly answer the question by way of demonstration, incorporating the exact SQL text of the original query:

```
  SELECT v.date 
       , SUM(v.`count(*)`)
    FROM ( -- inline view
           -- original (wrongish-looking weird-ass) query start here

             select   a.date, count(*) 
             from employee a 
             inner join department b on a.uid = b.id 
             where date(a.date) between current_date-2 and current_date  
             group by 1 having count(*)>1 
             order by date

           -- original query ends here 
         ) v
   GROUP BY v.date
   ORDER BY v.date
```

The query above may return the "expected result" shown in the question. But I strongly suspect that the return from this query does *not* actually satisfy the original specification.

Comment: date doesnot have time component, just groupby date and get the sum of the count

Comment: To get a "sum" of the "count", we could do the COUNT() in an inline view, and the outer query can do a SUM. But it's not at all clear how the query can return `'November 18,2019'`  and at the same time have `DATE(a.date)` satisfy comparisons to `CURRENT_DATE()`.  To echo a comment from @forpas, there is no conceivable way that the SQL text shown in the question will produce the output shown in the question, without the client doing a conversion to wonky string format. We are left guessing at datatype of `date` column; output makes it look like its VARCHAR, but that wouldn't work with BETWEEN